# Copy row from any table

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML page with 3 tables on it.  I want to be able to copy specific cells in a table row to the clipboard.  The row could come from any of the 3 tables.

Using the code below, I highlight and copy the row for a table with an ID of "final".  How do I make this work for any of the 3 tables?  I tried by `getElementsByTagName` and labeling them the same name but did not work - understandably so.  Is there a way to designate the selected table? I am trying to avoid copying the whole row and might eventually add the formatted msg to a new page rather than copy to the clipboard.

```
function copy_highlight_row() {
    var table = document.getElementById('final');
    var cells = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        // Take each cell
        var cell = cells[i];
        // do something on onclick event for cell
        cell.onclick = function () {
            // Get the row id where the cell exists
                
            var rowId = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
            var rowsNotSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for (var row = 0; row < rowsNotSelected.length; row++) {
                rowsNotSelected[row].style.backgroundColor = "";
                rowsNotSelected[row].classList.remove('selected');
            }
            var rowSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowId];
            rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            rowSelected.className += " selected";
            var cellId = this.cellIndex + 1

            msg = 'Title: ' + rowSelected.cells[0].innerHTML;
            msg += '\r\nDescription: ' + rowSelected.cells[1].innerHTML;
            msg += '\n\nLink: ' + rowSelected.cells[2].innerHTML;
            msg += '\nPublication Date: ' + rowSelected.cells[3].innerHTML;
            //msg += '\nThe cell value is: ' + this.innerHTML copies cell selected
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(msg);
            
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: Pass the table ID (or the entire table element) into your function when you call it.

Comment: The function is called once currently so the click event triggers the copy portion.  It sounds like I need a click on page type routine to identify the table, then pass the table id

Comment: `var cells = docment.querySelectorAll("table tbody td")` or if you have tables other than the ones you can add a class to the tables so you only select those. And instead of looking up the table, use closest() to reference the row.

Comment: @epascarello - thank you, would I then not need the table variable declaration? That did not work with or without the table var

Comment: Well document. is spelled wrong ;)

Comment: I caught the spelling mistake but it did not work for me.  When I try by class or name it seems to work on the first table but no others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a couple of the suggestions I came up with the following:

```
function highlight_row() {
    
    var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td')
    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
        // Take each cell
        var cell = cells[i];
        // do something on onclick event for cell
        cell.onclick = function () {
            // Get the row id where the cell exists
                
            var rowId = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
            var t_ID = this.closest('table').id 
            var table=document.getElementById(t_ID);
            var rowsNotSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            
            for (var row = 0; row < rowsNotSelected.length; row++) {
                rowsNotSelected[row].style.backgroundColor = "";
                rowsNotSelected[row].classList.remove('selected');
            }
            var rowSelected = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowId];
            rowSelected.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            rowSelected.className += " selected";
            var cellId = this.cellIndex + 1

            msg = 'Title: ' + rowSelected.cells[0].innerHTML;
            msg += '\r\nDescription: ' + rowSelected.cells[1].innerHTML;
            msg += '\n\nLink: ' + rowSelected.cells[2].innerHTML;
            msg += '\nPublication Date: ' + rowSelected.cells[3].innerHTML;
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(msg);             
        }
    }
}
```

At the end of the html I call the function.  The HTML contains 3 tables and this enabled me to click on any table, highlight the row, and copy the correct range of cells.